# AKS ARM template | Query

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-resource-manager

I am working to build an AKS cluster using ARM template. i have a situation where if i define OS Type to Windows, template should populate "WindowsProfile" and if i choose linux in OS type then it should populate linuxprofile.

here is the template with linux profile chosen, if i provide parameter OSType value to windows, how do i insert windowsprofile here.

```
     "name": "[parameters('AKSClustername')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters",
        "apiVersion": "2021-05-01",
        "location": "[parameters('Region')]",
        "properties": {
            "kubernetesVersion": "[parameters('kubernetesversion')]",
            "dnsPrefix": "dnsprefix",
            "agentPoolProfiles": [
                {
                    "name": "[parameters('agentPoolName')]",
                    "count": "[parameters('nodeCount')]",
                    "vmSize": "[parameters('vmSize')]",
                    "osType": "[parameters('OSType')]",
                    "storageProfile": "ManagedDisks",
                    "enableAutoScaling": "[parameters('autoscalepools')]",
                    //                        "availabilityZones": "[if(equals(parameters('availabilityZones'), bool('true')), variables('AVZone'), json('null'))]"
                    "availabilityZones": "[if(equals(parameters('availabilityZones'), or('1', '2', '3')), variables('AVZone'), json('null'))]"
                }
            ],
            "linuxProfile": {
                "adminUsername": "adminUserName",
                "ssh": {
                    "publicKeys": [
                        {
                            "keyData": "keyData"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
```

Comment: now if  i provide OSprofile as windows then it should populate following:

Comment: "windowsProfile":{
                    "adminPassword": "",
                    "adminUsername": "",
                    "licenseType": "Windows_Server"

                },

Answer (score 0):

To be honest it won't be really readable, maintainable with ARM Template.
I would suggest you to have a look at [Bicep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/overview?tabs=bicep).
It will compile to ARM template but will be more readable. Using bicep you would be able to do something like that:

```
//main.bicep

param AKSClustername string
param Region string
param kubernetesversion string
param agentPoolName string
param nodeCount int
param vmSize string
param OSType string
param autoscalepools bool

// Define common properties
var baseProperties = {
  kubernetesVersion: kubernetesversion
  dnsPrefix: 'dnsprefix'
  agentPoolProfiles: [
    {
      name: agentPoolName
      count: nodeCount
      vmSize: vmSize
      osType: OSType
      storageProfile: 'ManagedDisks'
      enableAutoScaling: autoscalepools
    }
  ]
}

// Add profile based on OSType
var propertiesWithOsProfile = union(baseProperties, OSType == 'Linux' ? {
    linuxProfile: {
      adminUsername: 'adminUserName'
      ssh: {
        publicKeys: [
          {
            keyData: 'keyData'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  } : {
    windowsProfile: {
      adminPassword: ''
      adminUsername: ''
      licenseType: 'Windows_Server'
    }
  }
)

// Create the cluster
resource aks 'Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters@2021-05-01' = {
  name: AKSClustername
  location: Region
  properties: propertiesWithOsProfile
}
```

Both Azure [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/bicep?view=azure-cli-latest) and [Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/deploy-powershell) supports Bicep.

If you do need to generate an ARM template, you could run this command

```
az bicep build --file main.bicep
```

It will generate an ARM template for you.